# Install C library on Windows

Tags: windows, cross-compiling, codeblocks

I want to migrate some programs from Ubuntu to Windows. These codes use the gnu/gsl library, which I installed on Ubuntu through configure -> make -> make install. However I am struggling trying to cross-compile the library using mingw-w64 (from Ubuntu), and I don't have even a clue of how to compile the library from within Windows itself (which I guess is the preferred solution rather than cross-compile anyway).

Thank you.

Comment: The title of your question is not very appropriate: it is not about installing the C library (which comes bundled with all C/C++ compilers), but about installing the GNU/GSL library

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have already installed CodeBlocks (recommended version: 20.03).
As for the MinGW/GCC toolchain I recommend installing **Msys2** by following the instructions on the [home page](https://www.msys2.org).
At this point you should:

- set the aforementioned compiler in CodeBlocks (after uninstalling previous installations of MinGW/GCC)
- the GNU/GSL library can be installed as a package (from the Msys2 shell) with the following command: 
    `$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gsl`

Now you can set (in your CodeBlocks project) the paths for the headers files and for the GSL static or dynamic libraries.